# Not able to setup STS in Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am a new to STS and Eclipse and need some help. I am getting following errors while trying to install or uninstall STS thru Marketplace.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.6.2.201501210735-r (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.6.2.201501210735-r)
  Missing requirement: Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.6.2.201501210735-r (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.6.2.201501210735-r) requires 'org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache [3.6.2.201501210735-r]' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 1):

The error looks like there is a problem finding a specific egit component from the Eclipse update repository while installing the STS components. Maybe there is some stale data in the p2 cache. Try to delete the "p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache" directory and try again. Maybe that helps. Otherwise I would recommend to use the ready-to-use STS distribution, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Download whole STS IDE from [Spring site](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all).
Everything works out of the box and you can install plugins you are using.

It is Eclipse pre-installed with Spring friendly features.